# Rolling (slot machine style) nav bar in Flash or SwishMax

Tags: flash, menu, navigation

Just wondering if anyone has an ideas on how this rolling (slot machine style) navigation bar was created. Maybe there's a Flash / SwishMax tutorial online somewhere? This effect is very hard to replicate because it animates very quickly onscreen, so any assistance to get me started would be great

Here's a sample of what I am trying to achieve: http://osc4.template-help.com/wt_28854/menu.swf?button=1

Thanks in advance,

Decbrad

Answer (score 0):

[Reusing actions: How to emulate functions in ActionScript](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/interactivity/slots/)

Adobe gives a tutorial using a slot machine example here are the [source files](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flash/interactivity/slots.zip).